# How could we add checkbox in filters while analyzing dashboards in Metrics Explorer(Monitoring) for GCP to select multiple entries in filters?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, dashboard, google-cloud-monitoring

How could we add checkbox in filters while analyzing dashboards in Metrics Explorer(Monitoring) for Google Cloud Console to select multiple entries in each filter options?
So that we can filter out multiple choices in each filters at the same time.

Currently we can select multiple filters in Dashboards of Monitoring but could not select multiple options from each filter for further comparison and analysis